# How get Uploader Name of Downloded video from youtube-dl?

Tags: youtube-dl

I have downloaded some video from youtube using youtube-dl from many different playlists. Now i want all video's title should be included there uploader's name or channels name without downloading all video again so which cmd i need i am using window 10.

Answer (score 2):

You may extract `uploader` name from `-j` JSON metadata. E.g. as:

```
youtube-dl.exe -j https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YOUR-URL | python.exe -c "import sys, json; print(json.load(sys.stdin)['uploader'])"
```

[-j](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#verbosity--simulation-options) option doesn't download a whole video.

Comment: ~oh my, works wonderfully, thank you kindly my good sir. ^^